# Running Batch File from Python

Tags: python, batch-file

I am trying to run a batch file through python; however, it is not recognizing the path. It stops reading the path after the space between 'Practice' and 'Folder'. How can I fix this? I've tried the r and using forward and backward slashes. Any help would be awesome. Thank you!

```
import os

Practice = r"C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Practice Folder\Practice.bat"
os.system(Practice)
```

> 'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Practice' is not recognized as an internal
>   or external command, operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change working directory to the script directory as you are using some relative redirection paths. Pushd changes current directory to any drive and can map network drives. The `&&` chains commands and only runs the right hand command if the left hand command succeeds. `%UserProfile%` is a standard environmental variable which is usually better then using a fixed path of `C:\Users\Username`.

```
import os
Practice = r'pushd "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Practice Folder" && Practice.bat'
os.system(Practice)
```

Comment: Worked exactly the way i needed! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try using `call` from `subprocess` module.
**You need to enclose the command only in double quotes.**

```
from subprocess import call

call(r'"C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Practice Folder\Practice.bat"')
```

(Notice the order of placing quotes...)

This would even work with `os.system()` provided you take care the order of quotation marks.

```
from os import system

system(r'"C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Practice Folder\Practice.bat"')
```

This should help fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use two types of quotation marks e.g.

```
import os

Practice = r"'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Practice Folder\Practice.bat'"
os.system(Practice)
```

As it is, your string does not contain quotation marks - you need to include quotation marks within your string or else Windows will think that `Folder\Practice.bat` is an argument to the command rather than a continuation of the file path

Comment: This gives the "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect." error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import os
Practice = os.path.abspath(r"C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Practice Folder\Practice.bat")
```

Edit:

Something like this worked for me

```
os.system(r'"C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Practice Folder\Practice.bat"')
```

Comment: Does it work if you copy/paste `"C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Practice Folder\Practice.bat"` into the command line?

Comment: It does not, it gives the error "'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Practice' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: Are you including the quotations marks? Because they're important

Comment: Ahhhh, it works. Your code here also works now:

os.system(r'"C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Practice Folder\Practice.bat"')

But now I have to figure out why it is not executing the whole batch file. It executes everything when I double click on the batch file but does partial when executing from cmd and python. Giving me the error "The system cannot find the path specified." from the batch file now.

Comment: Cool. If that gets you what you want, go ahead and accept the answer to close the question.

Comment: Although it runs, it stops my batch file on the following line and causes the following error:


C:\Users\Username>Desktop\Practice Folder\App\application.exe %read sample.dir  1>log\run_log.txt
The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: When I double click the batch file, it runs fine. But running the batch file in python or cmd, it gives me the above error.

Comment: The line in my batch file looks like this: Desktop\Practice Folder\App\application.exe %%read sample.dir  > log\run_log.txt